# How to find users that have taken more than one action?

Tags: activities

We want to identify the most active users (eg. those that register to several events, or made several contributions, or signed several petitions).

Is there already a report or a custom search that allow to search users that have more than x activities of the same type?

In the future, can we use the engagement index somehow to identify them?

To make things more complicated/useful, I would like to be able to filter these activities by date, so for instance finding all our contacts that have signed more than 2 petitions in the past year. Is there something existing that I haven't found yet?

Answer (score 3):

This may not be a comprehensive answer, but do you have this extension installed? https://github.com/progressivetech/net.ourpowerbase.sumfields

Some of these calculated fields used with advanced search could answer some of your questions.

> The benefit of making these items available as calculated fields is
>   that they can be searched in Advanced Search and used as a basis for a
>   smart group as well as for tokens in email and print communications.

Sumfields that are available:

> ```
> Total Lifetime Contributions
> Total Contributions this Year
> Total Contributions last Year
> Amount of Last Contribution
> Date of Last Contribution
> Date of First Contribution
> Largest Contribution
> Count of Contributions
> Average Annual (Calendar Year) Contribution
> Date of Last Membership Payment
> Amount of Last Membership Payment
> Name of the last attended event
> Date of the last attended event
> Total Number of events
> Number of events attended
> Events attended as percent of total
> Number of no-show events
> No-shows as percent of total events
> Number of turnout attempts
> Number attended from turnout attempts
> Number noshow from turnout attempts
> Attended as percent of turn out attempts
> No-shows as percent of turn out attempts
> ```

Comment: Hi Zachary, thanks to mention that extension from PTP, it's a really nice one. However, my focus was more on tracking activities. I might end up writing an extension soon

Comment: did an extension come of it?